# C# Console app with Selenium Grid 2

Tags: c#, selenium-grid

I have built an in-house automation framework with scripts developed in C# using Visual Studio Express 2010. These Tests have been developed using the Selenium Webdriver libraries.

The entire automation suite is developed as a C# console application.
We are currently trying to use Selenium Grid 2 to support parallel execution.
I can use Desired Capabilities to start and stop the nodes etc.

But can Grid 2 be used without NUnit attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Nunit does not support parallel execution out of the box. You need to use something similar to [Nunit.MultiCore](http://nunitmulticore.codeplex.com/documentation)

Grid has a hub and node architecture, that can accept requests in parallel. However it does need the test runner to send requests in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) Do you think we can use something like Parallel.Invoke to send requests instead of a test runner?

Comment: @user2021160- Possibly, but I don't think it is straightforward enough. Another alternative is to have tests in different assemblies and invoke multiple nunit processes in parallel (multiple threads). The drawback is that the parallelism is taken out of the test suites. Manual care is required to ensure that tests (particularly setup) are agnostic of each other.

Comment: If parallelism is a key, I'd also consider switching over to something like mbunit.